# Unsure where to right click to delete Unreal C++ class

Tags: c++, unreal-4, filesystem

Trying to delete a c++ class (this should **not** be this difficult!) and I have deleted the .h, .cpp, and binaries.  Next everybody says "now, right click on your .uproject file and select Generate Visual Studio files."  *Where* do i right click it?  I can't find the file in Visual Studio, and it doesn't give the option to generate the files in my file browser.  Sorry about the noob question, but I 've google searched to no avail.  thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be this difficult but unfortunately, it is.

You right click the .UProject file in your File Explorer.

It's also recommended that you delete the Intermediate folder as well.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't give me an option to generate visual studio files.  Does visual studio need to be up or something?

Comment: ok for some reason I tried again and it worked!  thanks!  Unreal really needs to make this easier though.